# How to specify size (dimension) of .eps when exported from matplotlib using savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib

An .eps is too large to fit in a two-column article. If I scale it down, the fonts in the graph would be too small to see.

I think make the .eps smaller is better than make the fonts larger then scale it down.

There is %%Boundingbox: in .eps file which controls the size of .eps file. I am wondering how matplotlib control this parameter when exporting figure to .eps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the size of the figure when you create it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[3.375, 3.375])
```

or later

```
fig.set_size_inches([3.375, 3.375])
```

The units are in inches (and the values shown make a square figure that will fit in PRE columns).  To make sure that all of the labels fit, I normally use `tight_layout`

```
fig.tight_layout(pad=0, h_pad=0, w_pad=0)
```

before saving